# rails 3.2 We're sorry, but something went wrong in production. log file doesn't log errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i'm using apache + passenger

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      RailsEnv production
      ErrorLog /home/rails/project_error.log
      CustomLog /home/rails/project_access.log combined

      DocumentRoot /home/rails/project/public
      <Directory /home/rails/project/public>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

it works fine in development but when i switch to production i got famous "We're sorry, but something went wrong." text.

the strange thing is development.log doesn't show any errors. if i precompile assets or do database migrations then it's all placed in log file but nothing on 500 errors. i have

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

in production.rb

project_error.log is also empty and the errors are logged in projest_access.log

```
[31/May/2012:22:22:35 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 393 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"
```

what have i screwed up this time?

Answer (score 7):

In your `production.rb` file update the following line:

> config.consider_all_requests_local = true

Set it to `true`, see if that helps, it should output the error to the browser.